# Как добавить дату и время доставки WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Собственно, сабж. На странице оформления заказа нужно добавить дату и время доставки. Погуглил плагины, но что то они не работают. Есть у кого варианты, как реализовать такую штуку?

Comment: заказы - это обычные записи в wp_posts с post_type="shop_order". Вы можете хуками в зависимости от способа доставки сфомировать дату доставки и потом при оформление заказа в мету сохранить это значение, чтоб отображать пользователю и админу

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev на странице оформления заказа еще нет заказа :)

Comment: @WPPunk да. совершенно верно. " Вы можете хуками в зависимости от способа доставки сфомировать дату доставки" и "потом при оформление заказа в мету сохранить это значение". ждал каких-то уточняющих комментариев как именно формируется дата доставки, чтоб более точно направить

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev Просто у меня возникло столько вопросов, что даже не знал, с чего начать. Какими хуками, где их посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Уже поздновато для ответа, но надеюсь, что кому-нибудь такой вариант пригодится. Он работает на основе плагина DateTimePicker - https://xdan.ru/samij-udobnij-datetimepicker.html

Этот код создает дополнительные поля на странице оформления заказа. После создания заказа, данные из этих полей сохраняются в базу данных и далее выводятся на страницах "Спасибо за заказ", редактирования заказа и в email-уведомлениях.

```
/* Register main datetimepicker jQuery plugin script */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_time_picker' );
function enabling_date_time_picker() {

    /* Only on front-end and checkout page */
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    /* Load the datetimepicker jQuery-ui plugin script */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_script('datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false );
    endif;
}

/* Display custom checkout fields (+ datetime picker) */
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'display_custom_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    /* Define the time zone */
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); /* Set the time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) */

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <h3>'.__('Срочность доставки').'</h3>';

    /* Hide datetimepicker container field */
    echo'<style> #datetimepicker_field.off { display:none; } </style>';

    /* Radio buttons field: Selected option */
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_option', array(
        'type'      => 'radio',
        'class'     => array('my-delivery-class form-row-wide'),
        'options'   => array(
            'Как можно быстрее'  => __('Как можно быстрее &nbsp;'),
            'Ко времени'  => __('Время доставки'),
        ),
    ), 'как можно быстрее' );

    /* DateTimePicker */
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_date', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-delivery-time form-row-wide off'),
        'id'            => 'datetimepicker',
        'required'      => false,
        'label'         => __('Укажите дату и время доставки курьером'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        'options'       => array('' => __('', 'woocommerce' ))
    ),'');

    echo '</div>';
}

/* The jQuery script */
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_delivery_jquery_script');
function checkout_delivery_jquery_script() {
    /* Only on front-end and checkout page */
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');
    jQuery(function($){
        var d = '#datetimepicker',
            f = d+'_field',
            r = 'input[name="delivery_option"]';

        $(f).hide();

        /* On radio button change */
        $(r).change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() == 'Ко времени' ){
                $(f).show();
            } else {
                $(f).hide();
            }
        });

        /* Enable the datetime picker field */
        $(d).datetimepicker({
            format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
            allowTimes:[ '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30',
                '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30',
                '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30']
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    endif;
}

/* Check that the delivery date is not empty when it's selected */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'check_datetimepicker_field' );
function check_datetimepicker_field() {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) && $_POST['delivery_option'] === 'Ко времени'
    && isset($_POST['delivery_date']) && empty($_POST['delivery_date']) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Ошибка! Вы должны указать дату и время доставки', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
}

/* Check that the delivery date is not empty when it's selected */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_order_delivery_data', 10, 2 );
function save_order_delivery_data( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) && $_POST['delivery_option'] == 'Ко времени' && ! empty($_POST['delivery_date']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_datetime', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_date'] ) );
    }
    if( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_option', esc_attr( $_POST['delivery_option'] ) );
    }
}

/* View fields in Edit Order Page */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_fields_value_admin_order', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_fields_value_admin_order( $order ){
    /* Display the delivery option */
    if( $delivery_option =  $order->get_meta('_delivery_option') )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Срочность доставки').':</strong> ' . $delivery_option . '</p>';

    /* Display the delivery date */
    if( $delivery_datetime = $order->get_meta('_delivery_datetime') )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Время доставки').':</strong> ' . $delivery_datetime . '</p>';
}

/* Display the chosen delivery information */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'chosen_delivery_item_order_totals', 10, 3 );
function chosen_delivery_item_order_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {;
    $new_total_rows = [];

    /* Loop through Order total lines */
    foreach($total_rows as $key => $total ){
        /* Get the chosen delivery values */
        $delivery_option  = $order->get_meta('_delivery_option');
        $delivery_datetime = $order->get_meta('_delivery_datetime');

        /* Display delivery information before payment method */
        if( ! empty($delivery_option) && 'payment_method' === $key ){
            $label  = empty($delivery_datetime) ? __('Срочность доставки:') : __('Время доставки');
            $value  = empty($delivery_datetime) ? __('Как можно быстрее', $domain) : $delivery_datetime;

            /* Display 'Delivery method' line */
            $new_total_rows['chosen_delivery'] = array( 'label' => $label,'value' => $value );
        }
        $new_total_rows[$key] = $total;
    }

    return $new_total_rows;
}
```

Данный код вставляете в файл functions.php своей дочерней темы. Код рабочий, протестирован на некоторых проектах.

Желающие могут довести его до совершенства.